# Cannot access Eclipse's repository

Tags: java, eclipse

First of all, there is Eclipse Neon on that PC but it is unable to create projects such as Maven. The error it returns is that the repository cannot be accessed (Connection refused). A picture is presented below. I tried to install the newest Eclipse version but same error happens.

```
[2018-11-16 09:01:31] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2018-11-16 09:01:32] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1000 No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest.
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:398)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.fail(CachingRepositoryManager.java:353)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:244)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1613)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

The same error while creating a Maven project on the existing eclipse Neon:

[image: The same error while creating a Maven project on the existing eclipse Neon]

The computer uses a proxy, I tried to disable it from Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Use proxy for ...

I tried turning off the Antivirus and the Windows Firewall but nothing. Any ideas what possibly it can be?

I checked some other problems like this one but the usual answer was that it is because the installation folder doesn't exists.

**Edit:**
I tried Help -> Check for Updates. It also gave the same error but I can access it from my browser and the internal web browser in eclipse.
[image]

**Edit2:**
It is because my university doesn't have access to Internet outside of a proxy and some of the Maven project repositories are trying to connect without the proxy (probably a glitch in eclipse), no matter that it uses Native settings (basically the proxy settings from Internet Explorer's options). Let me know if you guys know any solution to move entirely all connections through the proxy.

Comment: can you try with eclipse kepler?

Comment: Eclipse Neon is pretty old. Please upgrade. The two error messages are not related to each other. For Maven, the proxy must be defined in Maven's `settings.xml`.

Comment: Won't work - https://i.imgur.com/07LDyXa.png. Downloaded from here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Eclipse Kepler is six releases behind and not been maintained for years.

Comment: I cannot update it because of the installation error. Both errors are similar: Connection refused. I could fix it on one of the PCs here with settings.xml by setting a mirrors to Maven's repo but it won't fix the installation.

Comment: Directly download a package: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: Downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 64-bit from that link. Same error happening while creating Maven project https://i.imgur.com/N7cHOpy.png. Could it be something from the existing files from previous editions? https://i.imgur.com/IAxMSqf.png

Comment: Did you do the following to set the proxy for Maven? https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/set-proxy-for-maven-in-eclipse.html

Comment: Edited the question with the final cause. Let me know if you have any idea how to redirect all connections (no exceptions) through the proxy. Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> Native settings and these from Internet Options won't work.